# Android NDK UnsatisfiedLinkError flutter

Tags: android

I have made a custom flutter plugin for a tablet device.
The tablet's architecture is **arm64-v8a**.

I have libraries that work for **armeabi** architecture to support fingerprint on that tablet.

And the flutter library .so not working for **armeabi**.

So how could I use the flutter library .so for **arm64-v8a** and the fingerprint library which is **armeabi** for **arm64-v8a** architecture?

below is the screenshot of the APK analysis

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add this to your gradle

```
defaultConfig {
    ndk {
        abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'
    }
    .....
}
```

I had a similar issue before and it was solved [here](https://github.com/ammaratef45/zold-flutter-client/issues/122)

Also, [this article](https://medium.com/flutterpub/flutter-app-couldnt-find-libflutter-so-c95ad81cbccd) is describing it.

Comment: I also moved the libs from armeabi folder to arm-v7a folder